# What are the key elements to making a flat design?

Tags: layout, flat-design

As a beginner to UX, I would like to know the key elements to making a good, minimalist flat design that is easy on the eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smashing has the answers
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/09/03/flat-and-thin-are-in/
Flat UI Colors has the colors
http://flatuicolors.com/

Comment: Here at UX.stackexchange.com it is preferred that answers with links should summarise the linked content. This is so that your answer will continue to be useful despite any future link-rot.

Comment: Yes, an answer should actually *answer* the question, not just signpost people off elsewhere to go and find it for themselves. Links are fine for citing as the source or as the reference behind an answer, but you need to provide a full answer as well. (Although to be fair it doesn't help that the question itself was far too broad to be able to reasonably answer in this format in the first place.)

Comment: that's why I included the links...